# random and for-each within for-each analogues for sql server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2

i have correctly running code for mvc4 using c# as follows:

```
        try
        {

            foreach (var spec in db.Questions)
            {
                int[] ans = db.Answers.Where(m => m.in_Id == spec.in_Id).Select(m => m.in_AnswerID).ToArray();

                Random RandString = new Random();
                foreach (var prod in db.Sheet)
                {
                    SheetAns prodAns = new SheetAns()
                    {
                         in_SheetID = prod.in_SheetID

                    };
                    SheetAns.in_AnswerID = ans[RandString.Next(0, ans.Length)];
                    db.SheetAns.Add(prodAns);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "Success" ;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return "Fail => " + ex.Message ;
        }
```

this code is having large execution time.

I want to perform same operation using sql query or stored procedure for database.

[image]

How can we convert this code to pure sql server 2008 query(or stored procedure)  ?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the structure of the data *in the database*.  It is also helpful to show the desired results, so someone doesn't have to figure out what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

How about first changing your query itself, so that it you no longer have the ["select N + 1" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

```
// Your select then becomes:
var newSheetAns = 
    from spec in Questions
    join ans in Answers on spec.in_Id equals ans.in_Id into g
    from prod in Sheets
    select new SheetAns()
    {
        in_SheetID = prod.in_SheetID,
        in_AnswerID = g
            .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()) // can't "ORDER BY NEWID()" in linq.
            .Select(x => x.in_AnswerID)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    };

// Now add them. This is still going to be slow, because entity framework
// does not support bulk inserts.
db.SheetAns.AddRange(newSheetAns);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If this is not fast enough, you can translate the above LINQ statement into a raw SQL `INSERT` statement (using `ORDER BY NEWID()` to randomize the answer id selection).

This can then be directly executed from Entity Framework like this:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( <your SQL statement here> );
```

Comment: in_AnswerID  is supposed to be random from  db.Answers.where(m=>m.in_Id  == QueId)

Comment: It is selecting them randomly using `OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())` from `ans`. The `ans` result set contains those records `where  ans.in_Id == spec.in_Id`, exactly as in the code you have posted in your question: `where(m => m.in_Id == spec.in_Id)`. So I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Where is instance of  "prod" ... ?

Comment: @PranavLabhe Ok, I see that I forgot a piece. Corrected